# Webpack external library access with Vue web components

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-4, vue-cli-3

I create a web component with vue-cli.3 in order to use it in other projects with the following command:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name helloworld ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue
```

The component has a dependency on **lodash**. I don't want to bundle lodash with the component because lodash is going to be provided by the host application, so I configure webpack in vue.config.js like below:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        externals: {
            lodash: 'lodash',
            root: '_'
        }
    }
}
```

So this way, I successfully compile the component without lodash.

In the host application (the one that will use the component), I add the source path of the newly created and compiled component into index.html:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/helloworld.umd.js"></script>
```

Register the component in App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <demo msg="hello from my component"></demo>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "app",
    components: {
        demo: helloworld
    }
};
</script>
```

The **helloworld** component renders without problems. Every feature of the component works without problems but as soon as I call a method of lodash, I get;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'camelCase' of undefined
```

which means the component cannot access the lodash library that the host application uses.

I need to find a way to use the already bundled libraries in the host application from the components.

Is there a way?

Comment: Looking at the webpack docs, it seems you have `externals` set up incorrectly. You need your externals object set up like this: `externals: { lodash: { root: '_' } }`.I don't think you really have a dependency called `root ` that you want to be exposed as `_` :p

Comment: Another tip, if you're building a library that will be installed in another environment that includes `lodash`, ensure `lodash` is listed under `peerDependencies` in your `package.json`.

Comment: @chipit24 You mean the package.json of the environment? Because I don't package the component, it's just a simple script file that I include in an html file which registers itself as a Vue component.

Comment: No, I mean the `package.json` of your library: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.html#peerdependencies, https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-types/#toc-peerdependencies. Since you're not installing your package via npm, yarn, .etc. then it technically won't make a difference.

Comment: I don't publish a package. It's just a simple Javascript source as I've explained.

Comment: Yes, I know! That's why I prefaced my comment with "if". Anyway, did you resolve this issue or not?

Comment: Not yet :( I'm trying to find a way for the component to use the already bundled lodash library. Maybe I can solve it with require.context so I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 4):

The Vue config you used should work (see [GitHub demo](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)), so maybe there's something missing in your setup. I've listed the pertinent steps to arrive at the demo:

1. In `public/index.html` of a VueCLI-generated project, import Lodash from CDN with:

   ```
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. In the library component (`src/components/HelloWorld.vue`), the `_` global can be used **without importing `lodash`**. For example, display a computed property that formats the `msg` prop with `_.camelCase`.
3. To avoid lint errors, specify `_` as an [ESLint global](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) (`/* global _ */`).
4. In [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js), configure Webpack to externalize `lodash`:

   ```
   module.exports = {
     configureWebpack: {
       externals: {
         lodash: {
           commonjs: 'lodash',
           amd: 'lodash',
           root: '_' // indicates global variable
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
5. In `package.json`, edit the `build` script to be:

   ```
   "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name helloworld ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue",
   ```
6. Run `npm run build`, and then edit `dist/demo.html` to also include the `<script>` tag above.
7. Start an HTTP server in `dist` (e.g., `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`), and open `dist/demo.html`. Observe the effect of `_.camelCase` (from step 2) without console errors.

[GitHub demo](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @tony19. This was one of the methods I tried and it works but there are libraries that don't register themselves to the window like lodash does. So in the host application I register all of them manually to the window and it works this way.

Comment: Ok. What's an example of a library that doesn't attach to `window`? There's likely a different config required for that library.

Comment: Our own libraries which come from our own npm packages :-)